# Using DBD::SQLite on macOS High Sierra produces tons of "subroutine redefined" warnings

Tags: macos, perl

Briefly, when I use DBD::SQLite on macOS High Sierra, I get a ton of spurious "subroutine ... redefined" errors.

If I take this code and run it on either my iMac or MacBook Pro (both running 10.13.3 High Sierra)...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;
use DBD::sqlite;

$db_file = "./anything.db";

$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$db_file","","");
$dbh->disconnect();
```

It produces this:

```
Constant subroutine DBD::SQLite::NEWAPI redefined at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/constant.pm line 140.
Subroutine driver redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 31.
Subroutine CLONE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 73.
Subroutine connect redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 80.
Subroutine install_collation redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 160.
Subroutine regexp redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 178.
Subroutine prepare redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 186.
Subroutine do redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 200.
Subroutine ping redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 219.
Subroutine _get_version redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 230.
Subroutine get_info redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 240.
Subroutine _attached_database_list redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 247.
Subroutine table_info redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 262.
Subroutine primary_key_info redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 378.
Subroutine foreign_key_info redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 536.
Subroutine statistics_info redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 636.
Subroutine type_info_all redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 704.
Subroutine column_info redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 766.
Subroutine TIEHASH redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 885.
Subroutine STORE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 889.
Subroutine DELETE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 894.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_last_insert_rowid redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::last_insert_rowid redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_create_function redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::create_function redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_enable_load_extension redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::enable_load_extension redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::load_extension redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_load_extension redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::create_aggregate redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_create_aggregate redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_create_collation redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::create_collation redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::collation_needed redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_collation_needed redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_progress_handler redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::progress_handler redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_trace redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_profile redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::profile redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::commit_hook redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_commit_hook redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::rollback_hook redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_rollback_hook redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::update_hook redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_update_hook redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_set_authorizer redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::set_authorizer redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::busy_timeout redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_busy_timeout redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_backup_from_file redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::backup_from_file redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::backup_to_file redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_backup_to_file redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::table_column_metadata redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_table_column_metadata redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_db_filename redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::db_filename redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::register_fts3_perl_tokenizer redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_register_fts3_perl_tokenizer redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::sqlite_db_status redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::db_status redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::sqlite_st_status redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::st_status redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::compile_options redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::sqlite_status redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::OK redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DENY redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::IGNORE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_INDEX redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_TABLE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_TEMP_INDEX redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_TEMP_TABLE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_TEMP_TRIGGER redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_TEMP_VIEW redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_TRIGGER redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_VIEW redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DELETE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_INDEX redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_TABLE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_TEMP_INDEX redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_TEMP_TABLE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_TEMP_TRIGGER redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_TEMP_VIEW redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_TRIGGER redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_VIEW redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::INSERT redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::PRAGMA redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::READ redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::SELECT redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::TRANSACTION redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::UPDATE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::ATTACH redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DETACH redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::ALTER_TABLE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::REINDEX redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::ANALYZE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::CREATE_VTABLE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::DROP_VTABLE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::FUNCTION redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::SAVEPOINT redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::dr::dbixs_revision redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::dr::discon_all_ redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::dr::disconnect_all redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::_login redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::selectall_arrayref redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::selectrow_array redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::selectrow_arrayref redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::last_insert_id redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::commit redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::rollback redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::disconnect redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::STORE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::FETCH redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::db::DESTROY redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::_prepare redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::rows redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::bind_col redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::bind_param redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::bind_param_inout redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::execute redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::fetchrow_arrayref redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::fetch redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::fetchrow_array redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::fetchrow redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::fetchall_arrayref redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::finish redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::blob_read redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::STORE redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::FETCH_attrib redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::FETCH redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
Subroutine DBD::SQLite::st::DESTROY redefined at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm line 17.
```

If I add code to do things in the DB, the operations succeed, and the errors don't appear if I remove -w.  But I like my code to be "-w clean".

I'm a bit mystified by this.  Those are indeed the places where DBD::SQLite is sourced from.  I'm using the system perl at /usr/bin/perl:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/perl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66608 Dec  1 12:45 /usr/bin/perl
$ file /usr/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [i386:Mach-O executable i386]
/usr/bin/perl (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/perl (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
```

I've used homebrew on both systems, but neither writes in /System and /usr/bin/perl -V says:

```
  @INC:
    /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.18
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18
    .
```

(No, I don't have any modules in my current directory).

DBD::SQLite is in /System:

```
$ ll /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  87746 Jul 27  2013 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm
```

For what it's worth, the strings DBD, SQLite, and NEWAPI don't even appear in /System/Library/Perl/5.18/constants.pm :-(

There's only one SQLite.pm on the box:

```
$ locate SQLite|grep DBD 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man3/DBD::SQLite.3pm
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man3/DBD::SQLite5.18.3pm
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man3/DBD::SQLite::Cookbook.3pm
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man3/DBD::SQLite::Cookbook5.18.3pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite/Cookbook.pod
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DBD/SQLite.pm
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/SQLite
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/SQLite/SQLite.bs
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/SQLite/SQLite.bundle
```

My usual method of debugging - typing detailed posts into StackOverflow and figuring out the problem myself through confessional debugging appears to have failed.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to `use` the DBD module. It's loaded automatically by DBI when you call `DBI->connect`. Removing the redundant `use` will silence your errors.

Details: On most operating systems, `use DBD::sqlite`would fail -- the module is actually called `DBD::SQLite` (capital "SQL"). It succeeds on macOS because the filesystem is case-insensitive, so the module can be loaded using either name; however, this causes it to be loaded a second time by DBI.

Comment: Very interesting.  I've used DBI + DBD for 20-odd years and I've always loaded the DBD module via use before calling DBI connect..and apparently I've been doing that wrong for 20-odd years as none of the major drivers' docs say to do that.